# Cannot call model inside controller, zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to initialize model object inside the controller, but fatal error occurs.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Visits_Model_Visit' not found in C:\AppServ\www\zendApps\InspectionSys\application\modules\visits\controllers\VisitController.php on line 24
```

I am sing module call visits, It have it's structure of Model, View and controller folders.

The `Visits_Model_Visit` exists inside the model folder and I am trying to define object from it inside an action of the controller

```
public function addAction() {

    if (isset($_POST)) {

        $visitObj = new Visits_Model_Visit();   // an error occur here!

    }
  }
```

[image: Here is the structure of the peoject]

Comment: What's your project directory structure? Where's located your model? What's your model class filename?

Comment: I'll upload it, just a second

Comment: Do you have those lines in your application.ini? resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules" 
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1" 
resources.modules[] =

Comment: I have this problem sometimes with specific projects, I never found a good solution and tend to just avoid the problem by using the application level models. I know this doesn't help, but at least know you're not alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit] **I found it...** look at your `Bootstrap.php` that is under `/modules` and move it under `/modules/visits` and make sure it looks like below, that should fix it.

All I can say is to check a few things, normally everything will work when your module bootstrap looks like:

```
<?php

class Visits_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap{
    //put your code here
}
```

and your application.ini has these lines:

```
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
resources.modules = ""
```

This is my whole frontcontroller section and I do have access to my module level models. I know of no other settings to make modules work, although I'm sure there are many variations.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Visits_Model_Visit` exists in the **/models** folder (note the 's' on the end), firstly watch out for this...but I don't know how you set up your autoloader.

Comment: This would be correct in ZF 1.x as /models is a default route and will map to Module_Model_XXX.